# Error only shows at the back-end but not correctly at the front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make sure that the front-end of my app will display the error that I want it to display. I am purposely trying to create a user that already exists and therefore show my custom `User already exists. Please log in.` error.

It shows in postman when sending a request to the same endpoint, but at the front-end, the response just shows the following and not the actual error message I defined:

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/create', redirected: false, status: 409, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 409
statusText: "Conflict"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/user/create"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

The `createUser` controller:

```
export const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const existingUser = await User.findByEmail(email);

  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(409).send('User already exists. Please log in.');
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  const newUser = new User(email, hashedPassword);
  const saveToDb = await newUser.saveToDb();

  if (!saveToDb) {
    return res.status(500).send('Could not insert user into the database.');
  }

  const token = newUser.signToken();

  res.status(201).json({ token, id: saveToDb.insertedId });
};
```

The front-end submission:

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<CreateAccountFormInputs> = async (formData) => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);

            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            });

            console.log(res); // output shown above

            if (!res.ok) {
                setError(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
                return;
            }

            navigate('/login');
        } catch (err: any) {
            setError(err.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
```

Inside the `if (!res.ok)` block, I want to set the error to the custom message that should be returned by the API. But I can't set it if it's not returned.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to get the text from the response body. `res.status` is just a status code. In your case 409 or 500.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem to be in the body - here's a log of res.body:

`ReadableStream {locked: false}
locked: false
[[Prototype]]: ReadableStream`

What key should it be?

Comment: Try looking something up instead of trying to guess how things work. It will save you a lot of time in the long run. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response (`const textFromBody = await res.text()`)